# What's uibuild.xml used for?

Tags: android, ant

I'm now learning Android development from scratch and using ant to build apk.

I find that there're two files under `${ANDROID_SDK}/tools/ant`: `build.xml` and `uibuild.xml`.

I'm only familiar with `build.xml` because there's also a file with the same name under my Android development workspace, in which it refers to the `build.xml` in `${ANDROID_SDK}/tools/ant`.

However, what's `uibuild.xml` used for? It seems not be referenced by other files.

Answer (score 0):

uibuild.xml is used to generate the jar file for a UiAutomator test package.

The following command line script is used to create a build.xml ant build file in your test project directory that will reference uibuild.xml (which actually contains the rules for building):

```
<android-sdk>/tools/android create uitest-project -n <name> -t 1 -p <path>
```

See the following links: 
http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing_ui.html
http://developer.android.com/tools/help/uiautomator/index.html